# Data from PHP form is inserted into mysql database several times

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert, sum

I'm pretty new in PHP and MYSQL. I've got this form that I use to enter data into a database I created. I add up values from two fields in separate columns and insert the value into a third column (TOTAL_IN). Then I subtract another value (VALUE3) that's in another field from the value in a field in the third column (TOTAL_IN) and put that value in a different column. All these are in the same table. It works just fine, but the problem is that when I open up my database I see that the data has been inserted 20 or 100 times! How can I stop the data from being inserted so many times?

Please note that the submit button was clicked only once.

Here is what I use:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (id, date, value1, value2, total_in, value3, value4)
      SELECT '','$date','$value1','$value2',('$value1'+'$value2') AS SUM,
              '$value3',(('$value1'+'$value2')-$value3) AS SUM
      FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

any help?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT::: Here is what my code looks like now after your suggestions:

```
//From Ruddy's post
$total_in=$value1+$value2;
$value4=($value1+$value2)-$value3;

//From Amit's post
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(id, date, value1, value2, total_in, value3, value4) VALUES ('', '.$date.', '.$value1.', '.$value2.', '.$total_in.', '.$value3.', '.$value4.')";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
```

it works but it still enters the data many times.

Comment: you should not use mysql_query because is deprecated!
use instead PDO or MySQLi
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: i changed it to mysqli_query($sql) but now it's giving me an error

Comment: I don't understand as to why you are inserting the values that are being fetched from the same table. as if some sort of recursion?
I mean INSERT INTO $tbl_name and FROM $tbl_name.??

Comment: @admiralchip: You changed it to `mysqli_query`, that's good, but did you change the connect calls, too?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanks! i just did that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (id, date, value1, value2, total_in, value3, value4)
 VALUES( '', '".$date."', ".$value1.", ".$value2.", ".$value1+$value2.", 
".$value3.",".$value1+$value2-$value4.")";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

You need to concatenate the variables in php while writing in the query please see the syntax.

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

What you were doing was select all the rows of the table and inserting into all.

Comment: Dear admiral please check the syntax as you need to concatenate the variables while using inside the sql query. I mean with the help of dots.

Comment: oh! ok i didn't see the dots :)

Comment: Dear admiral if u see any syntax fault like missing dots then please make a suitable edit so that it help others too... cheers!!

Comment: it's working now. i added the double quotes in your solution to @Ruddy's solution. :) Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sum= $value1+$value2;
$sum2= ($value1+$value2)-$value4;

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (id, date, value1, value2, total_in, value3, value4) VALUES ('', '$date', '$value1', '$value2','$sum','$value3','$sum2')"
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I hate sums in the statement, so I took them out.

Comment: Your welcome, at least you ran into this problem now so you will know how to solve it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your query will INSERT as many rows as returned from the SELECT statement! Looks like your SELECT returns as many rows as there are in $tbl_name and you are re-inserting them in the same table!!

Comment: YIKES!!! alright, i see what you mean. how do i go about it? let me post what my code looks like now.

Comment: @Amit Kumar answer is the way to go. Just add double quotes when concatenating your variables : `$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (id, date, value1, value2, total_in, value3, value4)
  Values( '', '".$date."', '".$value1."', '".$value2."', ('".$value1+$value2."') AS SUM, 
    '".$value3."',('".$value1+$value2-$value4."') AS SUM2)";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: Try @Ruddy's proposal. It's cleaner. As for the multiple inserts, are you sure you're not looking at previous inserts?? There's only one set of values listed in the query!